# Poison queue is not created after certain iterations in service bus using WebJobs

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

Poison queue is not created after certain iterations (10) in service bus using WebJobs. Currently I am running Azure free edition and Azure SDK 2.7. I know Poison Queue should be created after certain iterations when Web job fails to process it. Is it due to free edition.

Comment: By `Poison Queue` you mean `$DeadLetter` subqueue. Right?

Comment: Nope, when WebJob iterates a particular message from queue and fails after certain iterations it will automatically creates a Queue with name "Original queue name" appended with "- Poison".

Comment: Bhanu, the WebJobs SDK poison queue handling you're mentioning is for Azure Queues, not Service Bus queues.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/#advanced-capabilities (you can refer to the url that I have provided it is supported by service bus also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has two types of queues: Azure Storage Queues and Azure Service Bus Queues.  Both have support for handling poison messages.  Azure Storage Queues handle poison messages by moving them to a Poison Queue and Azure Service Bus uses a Dead Letter Queue.

Here's a good post on handling poison messages in Azure Service Bus:

[Handling Poison Messages In An Azure Service Bus Queue](https://www.dougv.com/2015/07/handling-poison-messages-in-an-azure-service-bus-queue/)

If you are using Service Bus you should see your messages in the Dead Letter Queue not a Poison Message Queue.  You can use a tool like Service Bus Explorer to manage the Dead Letter Queue.

[Service Bus Explorer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/service-bus-explorer-f2abca5a)

Answer (score -1):

Try to throw exception.

```
try
{
  var a = 1/0;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```